# IE7 debugging toolbar like Firebug

Tags: html, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-7, firebug

I want to test my pages in IE7 and need a good debugging toolbar like Firebug..
I know there is the default IE Developer toolbar which comes, but that does not seem very helpful, specially for script debugging..

I need a tool like Firebug which can be very useful (like I can view what is there in the markup as well after script execution)

Answer (score 0):

Not even close to firebug , but the best i ever found is [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/).

Answer (score -1):

you can use IE9 and above and press f12, to check for lower version you can change the browser mode and document mode in it.